# iPhone X: UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext return image with potential loss quality ("broken pixels")

Tags: ios, iphone-x

**Note: This bug repeats only with iPhoneX and only with white text color.**

I have UITextView with the possibility of changing the frame size. When I try to get image with UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext its return image with "broken pixels" a near to edges of the text.

`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, opaque, 0.0)`

[image: image with scale = 0.0 (3.0 for iPhoneX as default)]

But when I change scale value from 0.0 to 2.0 "broken pixels" have disappeared and I get normal image without issues:

`UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(frame.size, opaque, 2.0)`

[image: image with scale = 2.0]

This bug does not occur with other iPhones or text colors.

I try to change `textView.textInputView.contentScaleFactor` value but it's not was helpfull.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What are you rendering the context into?

Note that you generally want image/texture widths and heights to be powers of 2. That may be getting messed up by the iPhone X's contentScaleFactor, which is 3.

(Most iOS devices are 2 these days, which keeps things power-of-2. But when you call UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions with 0.0, under the hood that becomes 3.0 on the iPhone X.)